# Combine days and hours when displaying relative time

Tags: momentjs

Is it possible to display the relative time using both days and hours using moment.js?
Like "2 days, 7 hours ago"

Or is there another library to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Another library you have to use `moment-duration-format` for converting days and hours format.

So, first run this command `npm install moment-duration-format`

And your code look like,

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-duration-format';

const time = moment.duration(moment().diff('2020-11-08')).format('D [days,] H [hours ago]');
console.log(time);
```